# How to run a method in ContentView when an ObservedObject changes in other class [Swift 5 iOS 13.4]

Tags: ios, swift, view, observableobject

Here is my basic ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View
{
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    init(model: Model)
    {
        self.model = model
    }

    // How to observe model.networkInfo's value over here and run "runThis()" whenever the value changes?

    func runThis()
    {
        // Function that I want to run
    }

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
            {
            // Some widgets here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my model

```
class Model: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var networkInfo: String
    {
        didSet
            {
                // How to access ContentView and run "runThis" method from there?
            }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it is accessible ? Or if I can observe ObservableObject changes from View and run any methods?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. If you want to runThis() when the 
networkInfo changes then you could use something like this:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var networkInfo: String = "" 
}


struct ContentView: View {
@ObservedObject var model = Model()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            self.model.networkInfo = "test"
        }) {
            Text("change networkInfo")
        }
    }.onReceive(model.$networkInfo) { _ in self.runThis() }
   }

func runThis() {
      print("-------> runThis")
 }
 }
```

another global way is this:

```
 class Model: ObservableObject {
   @Published var networkInfo: String = "" {
    didSet {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("runThis"), object: nil)
    }
}
}

 struct ContentView: View {
@ObservedObject var model = Model()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            self.model.networkInfo = "test"
        }) {
            Text("change networkInfo")
        }
    }.onReceive(
    NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name("runThis"))) { _ in
        self.runThis()
    }
   }

func runThis() {
      print("-------> runThis")
 }
 }
```

Comment: This is actually so helpful. Thank you so much @workingdog, I will now learn more about the useful onReceive() because of you!!!